# Moving servers has broken MySQL database driven google map

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm picking up a site from a previous developer and we're wondering why, after moving the site onto new servers, does the map on `http://69.94.34.32/map-of-hostels-in-the-lake-district.php` not display the pins populated by the xml file `http://69.94.34.32/xmloutputuk.php` as it used to do?

Here it is on the old servers where it *does* work: [[The map](http://www.independenthostelguide.co.uk/map-of-hostels-in-the-lake-district.php)] & [[The XML](http://www.independenthostelguide.co.uk/xmloutputuk.php)]

Straight after the move, loading the XML file in your browser gave you the following error:

> "This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

...which is why we rebuilt the xml file to make sure that's not the issue. But now we've got the xml file working again (by identifying and commenting out the problem pieces) the map pins *still* aren't displaying.

We're aware our new servers are PHP5 whilst the old ones were on PHP4, so might that be the issue? In which case what do we need to change?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA! Fixed it by including the following script in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
```

which was a suggestion posted in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056310/2703926).

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I'd say that the migration from PHP4 to PHP5 is, most likely, the culprit.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467448/using-php-mysql-with-google-maps), they mention that in PHP5, the DOM XML manipulation functions were replaced by the DOMDocument class, have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However http://69.94.34.32/xmloutputuk.php already uses the up-to-date DOMDocument class as you suggest. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: No problemo, glad you nailed the issue in any case. Please mark the answer as resolved when you can. Cheers